# How to get all the Sort keys for a given Partition key (HASH) efficiently?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to DynamoDB and I am coming from an RDBMS background. Is there any way to get all the sortkey (RANGE) for a given Partition key (HASH). I am not interested in the data, just the sort keys. What is the efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible to do exactly as you asked but you could add the sort key value as a separate column in the table.

Perhaps it would be simpler to have two separate columns in the table, one for your partition key and one for your range/sort key. Create a secondary index on the partition key to query and then return values from your new column representing your sort key.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that HashKey & RangeKey are specified while creating DynamoDB Table. You can use DynamoDB's [Query API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) and specify range key's column name in [AttributesToGet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.AttributesToGet.html) field of this API request. Please use the pagination support provided in Query API, else your system will suffer in case large number of values are returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use KeyConditionExpression as part of the DynamoDB [QueryAPI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html).

Here is roughly how you could do it in python:

```py
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

session = boto3.session.Session(region_name = 'us-east-1')
dynamodb = session.resource('dynamodb')

table_object = dynamodb.Table(table_name)

return_list = []

try:
    response = table_object.query(
        KeyConditionExpression = Key(partition_key_name).eq(partition_key_value),
        ProjectionExpression = sort_key_name
    )
except ClientError:
    return False

if 'Items' in response:
    for response_result in response['Items']:
        if sort_key_name in response_result:
            return_list.append(response_result.get(sort_key_name))
        
    return return_list
else:
    return False
```

Updated thanks to @Hernan for suggesting including ProjectionExpression

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the @Chris McLaughlin solution adding a ProjectionExpression attribute to the query. ProjectionExpression need to be a string that identifies one ("attribute_name") or more attributes ("attribute_name1,attribute_name2") to retrieve from the table.

```
response = table_object.query(
        KeyConditionExpression = Key(partition_key_name).eq(partition_key_value),
        ProjectionExpression = sort_key_name
    )
```

This will give you all the sort_keys in your table. It is not necessary to create an additional column to do this since the sort_key is already a column in the table.